# Python subprocess kill is not affecting SSH command as same as manually killing it on command line

Tags: python, ssh, signals

I have a SSH command that triggers an external application on the remote server, once this external application is triggered then it opens in several processes.
One of my requirements is that once the SSH is killed then all of the processes that was opened by it on the remote server will also be killed.

On one hand while using command line manually I succeeded to fill the above requirement as following:

```
ssh -t -t root@1.2.3.4 <command that opens in multi-processes>
cntrl + c => closes all remote processes successfully
```

On the other hand the above doesn't work when I attempt to execute it by using python subprocess.popen:

```
#Lets assume that below SSH command opens 4 processes of the external application
p = subprocess.Popen(ssh_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.kill() => Kills only one of the remote processes
```

Anyone have an idea what causes a different behavior between the above two methods?

Comment: Ctrl+C does *not* `kill` the process. It sends a signal...

Comment: How do you start :"command that opens in multi-processes" and what is your `ssh_cmd` in the lower example.

Comment: @OndrejK. The first example of manual SSH, <command that opens in multi-processes> is just a call to an IO generator application that is installed on the remote server (FIO io generator: fio --arg_1 val_1 ... --arg_n val_n ). In the second example it is also similar to the first including the SSH prefix (ssh_cmd ="ssh -t -t  root@1.2.3.4 fio --arg_1 val_1 ... --arg_n val_n")

Comment: I suspect it'll boil down to what signal does your remote process receive and how it reacts to it. In case you've called `ssh -t` from the console, it's gonna get `SIGINT`. When you kill `subprocess`, I suspect it gets `SIGHUP`. I was also curious what you run, and if shell is involved in Python side. I suspect it is with that command line, but it probably does not need to spawn another process for the `ssh` call and can just `execve` it. You can check try to find your run ssh from the command line, find its pid and send it both signals see if it makes that difference.